# Changing background Color in html and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval

I created an array containing addresses of images, now I want that these images should be randomly selected and displayed very smoothly not all at sudden, I want that it should start displaying slowly randomly out of the array.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the images to a div and use [Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for the slideshow

```js
var array = ['https://placeimg.com/200/200/any', 'https://picsum.photos/200', 'https://via.placeholder.com/200'];

var images = $();
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    images = images.add(`<div style="background-image:url('` + array[i] +`')"></div>`);
}
$('.slideshow').append(images);

var total = $('.slideshow div').length; // get the number of slides
var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * total ); // random number

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.slideshow').slick({
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    speed: 3000,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    initialSlide: rand,
    dots: false,
    prevArrow: false,
    nextArrow: false
  });
});
```

```css
.slideshow .slick-track div {
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slideshow">
</div>
```